# Linker error - undefined reference -gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

After running,

```
 Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/list
  $ gcc -c arrayImpl.c -o arrayImpl.o
```

Code directory structure, in windows(cygwin)

```
Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/stack
$ ls
main.c  stack.h  stackImpl.c

Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/list
$ ls
arrayImpl.c  arrayImpl.o  linkedListImpl.c  list.h  main.c
```

---

`Stack` abstraction depends on `List` abstraction, for data representation & usage.

`List` abstraction is as shown below,

```
/************ list.h ************/


/***************** Usage-start ************/
typedef enum{false, true}bool;
typedef enum {CREATE_NEW_LIST, DOUBLE_THE_LIST, HALF_THE_LIST}Op;

#if defined(ARRAY)

  /* To ensure Encapsulation(i.e., maintain invariants of array) */
  typedef struct List List;

#elif defined(LINKED_LIST)

  /* To ensure Encapsulation(i.e., maintain invariants of linked list) */
  /* User will not get access to node*/
  typedef struct List List;


#else
  #error "Wrong list implementation macro name !!!"
#endif


void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);
void *deleteItem(List *, int listIndex);
void *deleteLastItem(List *);


List* createList(List *, Op opType);

/***************** Usage-end ***************/
```

---

```
/***************** arrayImple.c **************/

#if defined(ARRAY)

#include"list.h"


/************ Representation - start ************/
typedef struct List{
  void **array;

  /* Following members for Housekeeping - Array enhancement*/
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;

#define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
/********************* Representation - end ************/




/************* Usage - start ***************/
List *createList(List *list, Op opType){

       ....
}

void insertItem(List *arrayList, void *newItem){
            ...
}

void *deleteItem(List *arrayList, int listIndex){
     ....
}

void * deleteLastItem(List *arrayList){
     ...
}
/******************** Usage - end *******************/

#endif
```

---

`Stack` abstraction, is shown below,

```
/********* stack.h *********/

#include"../list/list.h"

typedef struct Stack Stack;

Stack *createStack();
void push(Stack *, void *item);
void*pop(Stack *);
```

---

```
/*********** stackImpl.c *******/

#include"../list/list.h"

typedef struct Stack{
  List *stack;
}Stack;

Stack* createStack(){

  Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
  s->stack = createList((void *)0, CREATE_NEW_LIST);

  return s;
}

void push(Stack *s, void *item){
  insertItem(s->stack, item);
}

void *pop(Stack *s){
  void *item = deleteLastItem(s->stack);
  return item;
}
```

---

Below compilation says, with given below message, which does not involve linker,

```
Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/stack
   $ gcc -c -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c ../list/arrayImpl.o
gcc: warning: ../list/arrayImpl.o: linker input file unused because linking  
      not done
```

Below compilation fails, with given below error,

```
Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/stack
   $ gcc -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c ../list/arrayImpl.o
/tmp/ccapgYQI.o:stackImpl.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to 
   `createList'
/tmp/ccapgYQI.o:stackImpl.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to 
   `insertItem'
/tmp/ccapgYQI.o:stackImpl.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to 
   `deleteLastItem'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Question,

From above compilation command, Why GNU linker(`ld`) does not accept `../list/arrayImpl.o` file to find the definitions of `createList()`, `insertItem()` & `deleteLastItem()`

Below compilation **works**,

```
  Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/stack
    $  gcc -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c ../list/arrayImpl.c
```

Comment: Because `gcc -c` is compiling only without linking. Giving it `*.o` files is useless as the warning is friendly suggesting.

Comment: `-c` means compile only (don't link). So a `.o` file cannot be provided as it cannot be compiled (it's already compiled and needs to be linked).

Comment: `gcc -c` is for compiling, not linking.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  You missed my question. Please check the question again

Comment: Then show how you have compiled `arrayImpl.c` to produce `arrayImpl.o`

Comment: On saying, `gcc -c`, avoids assembling and linking stage, mainly `cpp` & `cc` are involved. `arrayImpl.o` is visible in the code directory structure

Comment: Note that the declaration in `stack.h` that reads `Stack *createStack();` is not a prototype; you need to use `Stack *createStack(void);` to state that the function takes no arguments.  As it stands, it takes an indeterminate number of arguments of unspecified type, but it isn't a variadic function (there's no `...` in the definition).

Comment: Also note that `<stdbool.h>` from C99 provides `bool`, `true`, `false`, so you don't need the definition `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`, though it does no great harm.  None of the four headers that are included in `stack.h` are actually needed by `stack.h`; you should not clutter your headers with unnecessary other headers.  The `Op` typedef is needed; the `typedef struct List List;` should be unconditional (the consumers of your abstraction shouldn't need to care how your list type is implemented; that is purely an implementation concern).  You should radically simplify your header.

Comment: Tons of useless code, when the reason was an incomplete command line.

Comment: @Jens I could be able to delete only 4 lines of code after reading your comment

Comment: this line: `$ gcc -c -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c ../list/arrayImpl.o`  should be: `$ gcc -c -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c -o ../list/arrayImpl.o`  Notice the `-o` to tell the compiler the name of the output object file.

Comment: there seems to be more than one file named: `main.c`  That is probably an error.

Comment: the file: `stackimpl.c` seems to be missing the statement: `#include "stack.h"`  Strongly suggest a header file for a *.c file have the same name as the *.c file with the only difference being the name extension is `.h` rather than `.c`

Comment: @user3629249 OK. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/7_Tree/Rooted_tree/Rooted_tree_Implementation_c), How do you want me to name `.c` ?

Comment: I downloaded each of the files in the linked web page on github.com.  They don't compile,  the main.c file contains a `main()` function, that is empty, so running this code (if it did actually compile and link) would do nothing.

Comment: regarding the linked code: 1) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, realloc, calloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 2) separate struct definitions from 'typedef's for that struct

Comment: regarding this line: `rootNode->item = malloc(sizeof(strlen((const char *)item) + 1));`  the `strlen()` function returns a `size_t` (unsigned long int)  so the resulting value passed to malloc will be `sizeof(size_t)+``,  probable not what you want

Comment: the function: `strcpy()` requires that the second parameter be a NUL terminated.  There is noting in the posted code to enforce that criteria.  Suggest using `memcpy()` rather than `strcpy()`

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("\n(%s)", (char *)(node->item));`  the format specifier: `%s`  requires the item to be printed to be a NUL terminated item (and it would be best if it is composed of only the printable ascii characters.)  However, there is nothing in the code to enforce that criteria.

Comment: this function: `preOrderTraverse()` is a recursive function, with no limit on the depth of the recursion.  Strongly suggest re-designing that function, perhaps to use loops rather than recursion.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  2 spaces will not show up if using a variable width font.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via 1 blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines.

Comment: in the file: `tree.h`, there is a 'header guard' around the system header files, but they always have their own header guard, so no need to duplicate that feature.   The code prefixed with: `Usage-start`  is referencing several struct definitions that are not available. (look at the main.c file for a prime example of this problem

Comment: the file: `multiWalkImpl.c` is including the file: `./list/list.h`, but that file is not part of the gethub.com project.

Comment: @user3629249 1) For your point: `printf("\n(%s)", (char *)(node->item));` in `visit` function, I think that function has to be passed by user. Otherwise my `Tree` abstraction is not an absraction. What do you say?  2) I did not check out correct code properly, it is different from my local repo. Will include all your feedback and ping you.

Comment: @user3629249 `./list/list.h` not part part of the project. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/7_Tree/Rooted_tree/Rooted_tree_Implementation_c/list/list.h) is the file

Comment: @user3629249 Symbols available in between `usage-start` & `usage-end` are symbols than can be used by user of `Tree` abstraction. So, user can use `Tree` type from that `typedef struct LCRSTree Tree`. Why would the author provide struct definition, that leaks `Tree` abstraction. So, struct definitions sit in implementation files(`multiWalkImpl.c` and `lcrsImpl.c`)

Comment: the file: `./list/list.h` has to be part of the files because 1) it is not a C library file and 2) the code will not compile without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -c arrayImpl.c -o arrayImpl.o`

That is missing `-DARRAY`. Without that the code in `arrayImpl.c` is conditionally removed:

```
/***************** arrayImple.c **************/

#if defined(ARRAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

this

```
Cygwin-PC ~/code_practice/Computing/stack
   $ gcc -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.c ../list/arrayImpl.o
/tmp/ccapgYQI.o:stackImpl.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to 
   `createList'
/tmp/ccapgYQI.o:stackImpl.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to
```

failed becuase you missed off arrayImpl.c

kaylum has the right answer, when you compiled arrayImpl.c you forgot -DARRAY

Comment: But linker accepts `arrayImpl.o` files for linking right?

Comment: seems not, why not just put arrayImpl.c

Comment: I did use linker to link `main.c` with multiple `.o` files in the past. If  `gcc` actually run `ld` after preprocessing(`cpp`), compilation(`cc`) & assembling(`as`), Does `gcc` take `.o` or `.c` to link? This is why I gave `../list/arrayImpl.o`

Comment: @overexchange It's quite unusual to compile more than 1 source code file at a time, If you do it the traditional way and compile stackImpl.c also , and then do `gcc -DARRAY main.c stackImpl.o ../list/arrayImpl.o` it will work.

Comment: @nos Actually your case is also correct, but it seems that cygwin-gcc is not working in my case. It still gives same error

Comment: Show how you produced `arrayImpl.o`

Comment: @kaylum `gcc -c arrayImpl.c -o arrayImpl.o` this is how I produced

Comment: Please add that info to question. It's wrong and is the cause of the problem. Missing `-DARRAY`.

Comment: @overexchange Then you have a local issue that we don't know about, and can't help you with, e.g. you are mixing up files and filenames, or you have #defines that hide code that you think is not hidden etc.

Comment: @kaylum Updated the question, Sir.

Comment: @nos - its unusual if you use make but quite common if people write their own script etc to compile things